# WCF Service fails to start when adding trace logging config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a working WCF service that I wanted to hook into so I can look at the logs. So, I added a .config file, and now my service will not start at all.

In my code I do the following:

```
private ServiceHost _myHost;
```

....

```
        _myHost= new ServiceHost(typeof (MyType), new Uri(baseUri));
        _myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (myInterface), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), hostName);
        _myHost.Open();
```

And, as mentioned, this works when I do not have a .config file. However, to view the logs I have to add a .config file that looks like this:

```
   <system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
     <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
           <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
              <filter type="" />
           </add>
           <add initializeData="c:\logs\Traces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              name="traceListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack">
              <filter type="" />
           </add>
        </listeners>
     </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
     <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
     <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" />
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The error I now get in the logger is `Failed to open System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` and it occurs at the instance creation of my `ServiceHost`. So, why does adding a logging config make any difference?

**UPDATE**

The logger is the ServiceTraceViewer, that is where I am seeing the error once I throw in the config. So, the logging is working, it is just breaking the functionality of the code. I read somewhere that if I use a .config that I **MUST** have an endpoint in the config. Is that true, and if so, is there a workaround to this since I am doing that via code

Comment: is it a typo, or do you have an unclosed `<system.diagnostics>` tag?

Comment: Are the permissions correct for the c:\logs folder so that [IIS / whatever you're hosting with] can write to it?

Comment: any event log messages that could help you spot the error?

Comment: @paul Yah, it was only 3 spaces, so SO did not display everything. It is fixed

Comment: @esskar Yes, the Failed to open error that I mentioned. That is coming from the log

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush yes, the perms are correct, the log file is where I am getting the Failed to open error

Comment: @JustinPihony if you are creating your service host in code, then you can override whatever is in the config

Comment: The trace logs were a bit misleading, so I ran the exe in debug with the config, and it threw an invalid element and .NET 4.0 dependency that I did not have. The traces actually had mislead what the problem was...

Comment: So you kinda fixed it? If so, could you please write and answer to your own question?